# How do I enable anonymous access for only subsites of publishing sites?

Tags: publishing-site, anonymous-authentication

How do I enable anonymous access for only subsites of publishing sites?

Comment: Please share the knowledge for how you implemented this, It would really helpful for the finding the solutions for us.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Site Permissions site and select Anonymous Access.

Select the Entire Site option and anonymous access will be enabled.

After the anonymous access is enabled you will find it listed in the Permissions as Anonymous Users.

Comment: Hi Mansi, Thanks for reply. Actually i have created a bolg in my site as a subsite. When i go Site Settings->Site Permissions. There is no option for anonymous access. How to get this option. if i enable it from central administration for my site then anonymous access enables for entire site but i want to give anonymous access only to my blog. Waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: Hi Feroze it was my pleasure.You donot need to explicitly provide anonymous access to the blog. All the users of the sharepoint site will be able to access it. Just try it out.

Comment: You have to enable anonymous access for the Web Application (zone) in Central Admininistration, this doesn't really enable anonymous access, but just enables you to go the site collections and enable anonymous access there

Comment: Thanks you all. I have enabled anonymous access from central administration. My blog still not accessing (http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/) but i noticed that if i visit blog posts it works check: (http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1) so whats wrong with default.aspx page. :(

Comment: Looks like you got it working? Both pages work for me.